# Possible to rename multiple Java packages in Eclipse with a single command?

Tags: java, eclipse

My Java project structure in Eclipse looks like this:

```
myproject
    src/main/java
        com.mypackage.mysubpackage1
        com.mypackage.mysubpackage2
        com.mypackage.mysubpackage3
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
```

But I've decided that `mypackage` is not a good name for the packages in the first group. Instead I would like to rename them to `mynewpackage` so that my package structure would look like this:

```
myproject
    src/main/java
        com.mynewpackage.mysubpackage1
        com.mynewpackage.mysubpackage2
        com.mynewpackage.mysubpackage3
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
        com.myotherpackage.mysubpackage1
```

The only way I am aware of, with my limited knowledge of Eclipse, is to right-click on each subpackage and choose `Refactor -> Rename`.

But because the package list is quite long, I am rather hoping there is a single command that I am not aware of that would allow me to rename all of these packages in bulk.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is but it's not obvious. First, you must switch from "flat" to "hierarchical" view (see the menu in the "Package Explorer" under "Package Presentation").

Now you should get a single package entry in the view which you can select and rename.

Comment: lol, I've just spent 45 minutes renaming my packages and then fixing each import statement in each class, before deciding to google it.

Comment: just an addition here: when the rename dialog pops up, notice there's a checkbox called 'Rename subpackages' which i use a lot

Comment: Any idea if one could also keep src/main/java and src/test/java synchronized?

Comment: @Arjan: No, you will have to do this once per source folder.

Comment: Too bad, this is indeed what I did. Not a real problem, unless test classes boldly rely on package-private visibility of properties in the test targets. Yes, refactoring package names might reveal some bad habits ;-)

Comment: I'm a fan of Navigator and never bothered much to understand the use of Package Explorer much. but I've wasted a significant amount of my life-time in doing this manually. Now I know package Explorer also is very powerful! Today you saved me from renaming 2500 file's package headers! awesome :]
Thanks a bunch :]

Comment: @Anand: I sometimes use both explorers when I have to move code around: I open the target location in the navigator and move the whole view into a different place (like the bottom of the perspective). Now I can have both explorers open and drag&drop between them without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

On Eclipse: Select your package and press Alt + Shift + R and type the new package name.

First check, the Projects Presentation must be Hierarchical.

Regards.