# How to rename all package names to lowercase

Tags: java, eclipse, package, refactoring

I have a large project with many packages that are CamelCase. I want to rename all of them to lowercase e.g:

`main.MyPackages.Utils` to `main.mypackages.utils`

---

What is the best/fastest way to do so?

1. The first approach I was thinking about was using the IDE (Eclipse
   in my case), but this is a lot of work and does not always work
   because in some cases it thinks the package already exists.
2. The second approach would be to write a program myself which handles
   this. The program should rename all folders to lowercase and replace
   all import statements in java files with lowercase packages.
   Sounds easier than it actually is, because renaming/moving non empty directories requires some extra work and on Windows it is not possible to create a new directory with lowercase name using Java.

Is there a better way than the two mentioned approaches? If not I will go with approach two. Maybe using a UNIX OS would be better.

Comment: Writing a program to handle this will almost certainly take longer.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I think he means that on Windows, if 'main.MyPackages.Utils' already exists it's impossible to create a new package 'main.mypackages.utils'.

Comment: @Simon then rename it to something arbitrary, delete the directory (if you have to), and rename again to the desired name.

Comment: @AndyTurner That was Simon said: java.io.File.mkdir does not create a file and returns false because it does not distinguish between Uppercase/CamelCase and Lowercase. At least on Windows.

Comment: @Simon also, see [here](https://superuser.com/q/65302) about renaming files to lowercase; adapt to rename only directories.

Comment: Or just rename the directory directly, if that's allowed.

Comment: @AndyTurner Renaming the directory directly does only work when it is empty.

Comment: @AndiCover, are you sure that import-Statements are the only thing you need to worry about? Do you use reflection with Java-FQN? Do you have configuration XMLs with FQN-Classnames? Maybe doing the rename-refactoring in the IDE is actually the fastest + cleanest way, even if it takes a while.

Comment: @Simon No, I am not sure^^ But in the project we don't use reflection. 
I guess I will use the IDE but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Did you try this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617055/139985

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I am working with the hierarchical view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Renaming all packages using Eclipse:

I tried to rename the packages using Eclipse. Soon enough I faced the problem with this approach. First merge of master branch in my local branch restored all old packages again. The idea was to rename the packages on a weekend when no one works on the project. But it still would have taken **5+ hours** per branch and I had to change at least the master and the last release branch to prevent merge conflicts. I realized that this does not work in my case.

### Renaming all packages using a custom Java program:

I wrote a Java program which performs following steps:

1. In the first iteration through all directories it copied all folders to a new directory with only lowercase names (The first subpackage was completely renamed to prevent problems on Windows hosts).
2. Then the program started a second iteration through the new directory and renamed all import packages in Java files. For most imports this is quiet simple but I needed to use reflection to correctly rename static imports and imports of Enums in Java classes e.g `import my.package.MyClass.MyEnum`.
3. The next step of the program was to rename all other occurrences of the old package names found in Eclipse e.g. TestNG XML files, ...
4. The last step was to delete the old folders.

The runtime of the program is about 2 minutes per branch. The updated project compiles and I did not face any issues.

---

I did not add any code because the program is only working for this project. Maybe it still helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use IntelliJ Idea IDE and refactoring mentioned is lot easier.
You just have to right click and change the package name as you mentioned, this will update package name every where this was being used.
Let me know if it works.
[See the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REMuw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be performed with two steps using an intermediate package name:

- Right-click on the package `main.MyPackages.Utils` and select Refactor -> Rename...
- Enter `main.mypackages2.utils2` (check `Rename subpackages` if you have subpackages) and click OK

Now repeat the same and rename `main.mypackages2.utils2` to `main.mypackages.utils`.

Comment: I know that but imagine having a big project with about 200 or more packages. This does not scale. It will take some time and in the meantime other developers will merge their commits to master branch which then most likely will lead to merge conflicts. I guess this is a task for the weekend.

Comment: @AndiCover I'm not sure why you think it doesn't scale. It is just two fast actions performed by the IDE instead of one.

Comment: I have to do it for all packages, not just one... The package mentioned in the question was just an example. I have many more sub packages and almost all use CamelCase.